# Calculate monthly sums for multiple columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing years in the first column, months in the second, days in the third, and then rainfall data for different cities (LON and NYC) in the fourth and fifth columns, as shown below:

```
mat1 = matrix(c(rep(1979, each=360), rep(1:12, each=30), rep(seq(1, 30, by=1), times=12), 
            rep(seq(5, 25, by=5), times=72), rep(seq(1, 9, by=1), times=40)), nrow=360, ncol=5)

colnames(mat1) = c("Year", "Month", "Day", "LON", "NYC")
```

I want to calculate monthly sums for each city. The output should take the form:

```
    LON NYC
Jan  x   x
Feb  x   x
Mar  x   x
................
```

I have tried:

```
aggregate(LON ~ Month + Year, mat1, sum)
```

but this does not output data in the format I want, and crucially it also only allows me to calculate for one city (column) at a time. How can I adapt the above to work for all cities and output in the desired format?

Comment: Get all your cities in one column(wide to long), group, summarise?

Comment: `aggregate(cbind(LON, NYC) ~ Month + Year, mat1, sum)` or leave out Year depending on what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr`. We need to convert the matrix to data frame before using the `group_by` and `summarize_at` function.

```
library(dplyr)
mat1_sum <- mat1 %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(LON, NYC), sum)
mat1_sum
# # A tibble: 12 x 3
#    Month   LON   NYC
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1     1   450   141
#  2     2   450   150
#  3     3   450   159
#  4     4   450   141
#  5     5   450   150
#  6     6   450   159
#  7     7   450   141
#  8     8   450   150
#  9     9   450   159
# 10    10   450   141
# 11    11   450   150
# 12    12   450   159
```

Comment: This works really nicely - thanks very much @www. In reality I have dozens of cities so is there a way to modify summarise_at to include all cities?

Comment: @DJ-AFC Probably `mat1_sum <- mat1 %>% as.data.frame() %>% group_by(Month, Cities) %>% summarize_at(vars(LON, NYC), sum)`

Answer (score 2):

Arguably complicating things but a `dplyr`-`tidyr` option. This uses the newer `pivot_*` functions in place of `gather`/`spread`. A purely `dplyr` option shown by @www is probably more efficient.

```
as.data.frame(mat1) %>% 
   pivot_longer(LON:NYC,names_to = "city")  %>% 
   group_by(Year,Month,city) %>% 
   summarise(Sum = sum(value)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = city,values_from = Sum)
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   Year, Month [12]
    Year Month   LON   NYC
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  1979     1   450   141
 2  1979     2   450   150
 3  1979     3   450   159
 4  1979     4   450   141
 5  1979     5   450   150
 6  1979     6   450   159
 7  1979     7   450   141
 8  1979     8   450   150
 9  1979     9   450   159
10  1979    10   450   141
11  1979    11   450   150
12  1979    12   450   159
```

Comment: Thank you. I went with the solution of @www but the above is another nice solution

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
> aggregate(mat1[,4:5],list(mat1[,2]),sum)
   Group.1 LON NYC
1        1 450 141
2        2 450 150
3        3 450 159
4        4 450 141
5        5 450 150
6        6 450 159
7        7 450 141
8        8 450 150
9        9 450 159
10      10 450 141
11      11 450 150
12      12 450 159
```